# 3D Vectors - Calculating velocity components to reach a target

Tags: vectors, physics

I found this golf game, and it led me to taking on a little physics challenge. I am trying to hit my ball into the hole perfectly every single time. I can add velocity on the x,y,z axis.

The things I know are:

- The gravity                  (30 units/s)
- My initial vertical velocity (20 units/s)
- The ball and hole positions

Now there is some type of drag, represented by the value of 0.5. This is computed so the surface area isn't taken into account. The weight of the ball is 1

I'm not sure how to account for drag but this puts me in the right direction:

```
    gravity    = 30
    velocity_y = 20   //Vertical
        
    time = (velocity_y / gravity) * 2
        
    velocity_x = (target.x - start.x) / time
    velocity_z = (target.z - start.z) / time
```

As I said this gets me close but I am not sure how to account for the drag. Also when the ball is lower/higher it doesn't take that into account.

I attempted to include:

```
time_rise = velocity_y / gravity

height    = start.y + velocity_y * time_rise - 0.5 * gravity * (time_rise ^ 2)

time_fall = √(2 * height / gravity)

time = time_rise + time_fall
```

When I used this time value instead, I get some strange results for the fall time, here is a simple example of the issue I am having:

> Target: (53.0, -0.9, -4.0)
> Start:  (35.0, 0.1, -4.0)
>
> RiseTime = 0.6666667
> Height   = 6.736667
> FallTime = 20.10473

This fall time is way off, the point is only 1 unit lower than me. I am getting most of my maths for this from

http://www.convertalot.com/ballistic_trajectory_calculator.html

Comment: One bug is that you’re using the same vertical distance for both the rise and fall of the ball’s path.

Comment: At low speeds, drag is approximately linear, which means that the ball feels a force that proportional to and in the opposite direction of his velocity. That’s likely the model being used in the game. It’s easy enough to account for this, but the ball’s path is no longer a simple parabola, so you can’t use the formulas from that web site.